# No such file or directory-gcc

Tags: macos, gcc

Am trying to check gcc version in terminal (Mac)

am using os x - yosemite 10.10

Using this command in Terminal ----->$gcc version

```
 couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.0.0'
 i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: version: No such file or directory
 i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: no input files
```

pls suggest !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to compile a file named "version".  Try

```
$ gcc --version
```

instead.